# Background only appears 3/4ths down time

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a simple visual effect.  When the user's mouse gets closer to the "Oblivion" picture, a thick gray "border" appears around it.  However, I don't want to use an actual border because 1) I want both the image and the "border" to have curved corners.  2) I want the "border" to eventually have text on its underside.  So instead I used a background that is invisible until the user hovers over it.

However, the results are really wonky.  The background only displays about 3/4s of the way down the image.  What's the deal?

```css
img {
  width: 100px;
}

.gameContainer {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0px 20px;
}

.gameContainer:hover {
  background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 70%);
  /*Why oh why does this background only show up 3/4s down the image? */
}

.game {
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<span class="gameContainer"><img src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/4/4b/The_Elder_Scrolls_IV_Oblivion_cover.png" class = "game"></span>
```

Comment: display:inline-block to the span

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.gameContainer` is `display: inline`: Its content height will automatically be set to its surrounding block's line height.

Try `display: inline-block` instead:

```css
.gameContainer {display: inline-block}

/*Your previous code*/
img {width: 100px}
.gameContainer {
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0px 20px;
}
.gameContainer:hover {background-color: hsl(0, 0%, 70%)}
.game {border-radius: 10px}
```

```html
<span class="gameContainer"><img src = "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/4/4b/The_Elder_Scrolls_IV_Oblivion_cover.png" class = "game"></span>
```